# big space between text and diagram

Tags: chess, chessboard, xskak

I wish to create a diagram that has text appears vertically next to it. The "pawns" is not what I want. So at best, I try to do it with "basic". 
In my MWE, the "basic" appears vertically but there's a big gap in between. I like to center it as well. Thank you for your advice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xskak,chessboard}
\parindent=0pt
\addtolength{\voffset}{-1in}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-1in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{2.95cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{10\baselineskip}
%**************************************************
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.10\linewidth}
\rotatebox{90}{\centering\textbf{basic}}%****** basic vertical but has a big space
\smallskip
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.35\linewidth}
\chessboard[smallboard,setfen=3k4/8/2Q5/4K3/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1]
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.35\linewidth}
\chessboard[smallboard,setfen=8/8/2k5/7R/6R1/8/5K2/8 w - - 0 1]
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.35\linewidth}
\chessboard[smallboard,setfen=1k6/7R/3K4/8/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1]
\end{minipage}%   
\vspace{.40cm}

%**** pawns appear horizontal *****************
pawns
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.35\linewidth}
\chessboard[smallboard, setfen=8/8/8/8/8/1k6/7P/4K3 w - - 0 1]
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.35\linewidth}
\chessboard[smallboard,setfen=8/8/8/8/4k3/4p3/4K3/8 w - - 0 1]
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.35\linewidth}
\chessboard[smallboard,setfen=8/1k6/8/8/1PK5/8/8/8 w - - 0 1]
\end{minipage}% 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\rotatebox{90}{\makebox[0.28\linewidth]{\textbf{pawns}}}`.

Comment: @Ulrike - As always, thank you for your advice.